# Render HTML Static Pages from ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to build a website/web ( similar with Airbnb) app with ReactJS and RoR as backend endpoint.
My problem is that I am new to the whole javascript ecosystem and I have some questions. 
I have a full html5 static theme ( or tamplate ) with all the css, html files and so on, and i want to use react to make some content dynamic indise this theme html pages, and some other ( like about page and help ) keep it static html page.
My qustion is that, can I somehow with react-router or some other package add links to my static-pages from react? or I have to render everything with react and convert it to components? 
In short, can i have react app mixed with static html pages? or everything should become a single page application?

Answer (score 0):

Everything in react should be component based. React router is based on component too. So you can't serve static Html with react router until you wrap them into a react component.

Comment: with server side rendering is possible to serve static HTML ?

Comment: React support serve side rendering. But there is no point of serving static Html from server.

Comment: Ok thank you. So i guess that i have rewrite everything from the theme i bought in components!

Comment: But if you want for some reason insert some html from external resources - ya, you better do that on client side the way I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Technicaly you can render html inside react component.
It can be accomplished via [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: '<h1>Some text</h1>'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```